# Youtube Insert error credential

Tags: java, insert, youtube

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).addRefreshListener(new CredentialRefreshListener() {
          @Override
          public void onTokenResponse(Credential credential, TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
            // Handle success.
            System.out.println("Credential was refreshed successfully.");
          }

          @Override
          public void onTokenErrorResponse(Credential credential,
              TokenErrorResponse tokenErrorResponse) {
            // Handle error.
            System.err.println("Credential was not refreshed successfully. "
                + "Redirect to error page or login screen.");
          }
        })
        .build();;
    credential.setAccessToken(pushOvpRequest.getConnectorYoutube().getAccessToken());
    credential.setRefreshToken(pushOvpRequest.getConnectorYoutube().getRefreshToken());
    System.out.println("refresh token = " + pushOvpRequest.getConnectorYoutube().getRefreshToken());
    // YouTube object used to make all API requests.
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("X").build();

    System.out.println("check = " + credential.getAccessToken());
    // We get the user selected local video file to upload.
    File videoFile = getVideoFromUser();
    System.out.println("You chose " + videoFile + " to upload.");

    // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
    Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

    /*
     * Set the video to public, so it is available to everyone (what
     * most people want). This is actually the default, but I wanted you
     * to see what it looked like in case you need to set it to
     * "unlisted" or "private" via API.
     */
    VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
    status.setPrivacyStatus(pushOvpRequest.getPrivacyStatus());
    videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

    // We set a majority of the metadata with the VideoSnippet object.
    VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

    /*
     * The Calendar instance is used to create a unique name and
     * description for test purposes, so you can see multiple files
     * being uploaded. You will want to remove this from your project
     * and use your own standard names.
     */
    snippet.setTitle(pushOvpRequest.getTitle());
    snippet.setDescription(pushOvpRequest.getDescription());

    // Set your keywords.
    // TODO set tags
     List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
     tags.add("test");
     tags.add("example");
     tags.add("java");
     tags.add("YouTube Data API V3");
     tags.add("erase me");
     snippet.setTags(tags);

    // Set completed snippet to the video object.
    videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(videoFile)));
    mediaContent.setLength(videoFile.length());

    /*
     * The upload command includes: 1. Information we want returned
     * after file is successfully uploaded. 2. Metadata we want
     * associated with the uploaded video. 3. Video file itself.
     */
    YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);

    // Set the upload type and add event listener.
    MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

    /*
     * Sets whether direct media upload is enabled or disabled. True =
     * whole media content is uploaded in a single request. False
     * (default) = resumable media upload protocol to upload in data
     * chunks.
     */
    uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

    MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
        public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
            switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
            case INITIATION_STARTED:
                System.out.println("Initiation Started");
                break;
            case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                System.out.println("Initiation Completed");
                break;
            case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                System.out.println("Upload in progress");
                System.out.println("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getProgress());
                break;
            case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                System.out.println("Upload Completed!");
                break;
            case NOT_STARTED:
                System.out.println("Upload Not Started!");
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

    // Execute upload.
    Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

    // Print out returned results.
    System.out.println("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
    System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedVideo.getId());
    System.out.println("  - Title: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
    System.out.println("  - Tags: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTags());
    System.out.println("  - Privacy Status: " + returnedVideo.getStatus().getPrivacyStatus());
    System.out.println("  - Video Count: " + returnedVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount());

} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have the following error in the console:

> Throwable: null java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:78)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:75)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:303)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:586)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:300)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:505)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.handleResponse(Credential.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1041)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:436)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:327)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:415)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:340)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:458)
>     at ProcessPush.processUpload(ProcessPush.java:257)  at
>   ProcessPush.push(ProcessPush.java:129)    at
>   PushOvpRequestHandlerThread.run(PushOvpRequestHandlerThread.java:43)

This code was working yesterday but it just stop working this morning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your code problem, it's their server. I also have same problem, it started this morning, and until then it worked. Even using new references didn't help me, and I spent all day trying to resolve it. Also, cannot find support to see if they know when is that going to be fixed.

See this: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6354

Comment: Gosh ok I already spent a few hours looking at it also seeking in for a status page, also in Google groups and ... everywhere!